# How to check which users have been created by specific stored procedure in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure, which creates different username and password.But i have condition that for next time when stored procedure is called, it should delete previous user created by same stored procedure.And we are not supposed to store user details in table.
So could anyone can suggest me how to know those users which are created by only this stored  procedure?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the stored procedure calls CREATE LOGIN/USER or the stored procedure adds a row to your own user table?

Comment: Hi,yes, Stored procedure call CREATE LOGIN/USER and may create multiple user at a time.

Comment: The only to do this without creating your own local log table is to delete the user regardless of whether or not it was created in the stored procedure..

The answer from Anti-weakpasswords is the real solution

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. What should you do when your question is answered - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You can't without storing something uniquely identifying, particularly if (when) users/logins are dropped and recreated by other processes than the stored procedure.

Perhaps you could store just the principal_id and create_date from [sys.server_principals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx), and the same from [sys.database_principals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx); nothing identifying in particular, but the pair together should be a good indication that these are the right rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my boss doesn't let us to save any kind of data and He wants me to find out any other possible way. If we cant find out any other way then I think your solution will be best one. Thanks again